# Problemas con datos de array en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

estoy tratando de pasar datos json a javascript, para elaborar un grafico de barras, el problema es que no me trae los datos al array "cantidades" y no se genera el grafico, ya probe el archivo php y esta ok, ya probe extraer los datos con javascript y $.ajax y los trae, pero al llevarlos a "data: cantidades," es el problema, me podrian ayudar, no tengo experiencia con javascript, de antemano gracias.

para realizar la consulta mas sencilla datos_chart.php solo tiene:

```
$data = array("porrevisar"=>3,"porreparar"=>5,"reparado"=>7,"danado"=>1);

//now print the data

print json_encode($data);
```

y este devuelve:

porrevisar: 3 porreparar: 5 reparado: 7 danado: 1

que es exactamente lo que quiero

```
    /* ********Archivo Javascript**********/
$(function() {
    'use strict';
    /* ********BarChart1**********/
    $.ajax({
        url: "../pages/charts/datos_chart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (object) {
            var cantidades=[object.porrevisar, object.porreparar, object.reparado, object.danado];
            var data = {
                labels: ["Por Revisar", "Por Reparar", "Reparado", "Dañado"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Status de Reparaciones',
                    data: cantidades,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            };
        },
    });
```

Comment: Hola! Puedes pasar el código datos_chart.php? Un saludo.

Comment: Y tu json que devuelve `datos_chart.php` como es?, si colocas el json la comunidad podra ayudarte con una respuesta mas concisa.

Comment: te muestra algún error en consola? ya hiciste un `console.log(object)` para ver la estructura de la respuesta desde el servidor? si te esta trayendo un json tendrás que hacerle `object = JSON.parse(object)`